# Waterproof membrane under alcove tub? Tiling the bathroom floor

Tags: bathroom, waterproofing, bathtub, remodeling, tiling

I’ve completely demoed my bathroom, I’m going to install the alcove tub and then tile the floor. It’s a one story house and it’s a concrete subfloor. My question is: do I apply the waterproof membrane on the entire floor, under the tub? Or do I install the tub and then apply the waterproof membrane? I live near the golf coast so it is very humid and wet most of the year. That’s why I’m thinking to put the waterproof membrane down. My garage doesn’t have a moisture barrier and the concrete in there gets very wet daily. Anyone have a idea for this on a side note...?

Comment: Your Garage slab is getting wet from the underside ??  If the ground under your house is so wet that it comes up through the slab then you may have bigger problems.

Comment: Yeah I believe so. Hard to know for sure I guess? But it is very humid also. The slab just gets very wet and anything I keep in the garage tends to mold quickly. I planned to buy a dehumidifier. Just wasn’t sure if there was a better route to go. It seems the slab in my bathroom hasn’t gotten wet like the garage has. Hopefully that can rule anything too bad out? Either way. Any tips for me to try and figure out what could be the cause if it’s coming up through the slab?